# TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity)

Tags: ssl, udp, firewall, openvpn

I have recently installed an OpenVPN service on my Google Cloud Platform (Debian 10 Server) in order to test connecting to internet on this VPN protocol. The config file that is created by the server, however, fails to connect to internet when I import it in Windows 10 OpenVPN Client that I currently use to connect to internet using other config files. During set up, I installed ufw firewall and chose a password-less user and UDP connection according to a search in Google. Anyways, the config files that I have created this way all fail to connect from Windows returning a "TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity)" as noted in the log.

Does this TLS error mean my Windows client can't reach the server  due to some wrong permission/firewall settings on the server side (I have already allowed OpenVPN Client for Windows on my firewall on my Windows client)?

What changes should I make to the OpenVPN set up during installation on the server to make it work? Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance.